# How does Django model save data that is cleaned?

Tags: django, django-models

I've seen bits and pieces of this, but am having trouble putting it all together. Let's say I have a `model` with a `field`:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = models.CharField(...)
```

And I want to remove all of the "x's" from `my_field` and save it:

```
def clean(self):
    x_less = self.my_field.replace('x', '')
```

How do I get `x_less` to the `save` method? or how does the `cleaned` data get saved?

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.my_field = x_less #??????
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

If there is a good tutorial that I missed somewhere, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update:

You have to return from your clean method:

```
def remove_x(self):
    x_less = self.my_field.replace('x', '')
    return x_less
```

And assign the returned value in the save method:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.my_field = self.remove_x()
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

### Old answer, but still useful

Letting the user provide some input and later change that input without a previous warning it will result in bad user experience.

Following your example use case: If you don't want `x`s to be in your input, provide a validator for that field:

```
def x_validator(value):
    if 'x' in value:
        raise ValidationError(
            "x character is no allowed.",
            params={'value': value}
        )

class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = models.CharField(validators=[x_validator], ...)
```

Said that, if you want to modify a model instance just before or after being saved. Take a look in to [pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save) and [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save) signals.

Comment: I'm using it to remove grouping markers from a number to save space in the data base. I re-assign these markers in the __str__ method. Because the number is a set length, it throws a max_length error with the markers in.

Comment: @CarlBrubaker, I post an update in order to answer your exact question, but I really encourage you to look into post_save  presave_signals.  An also, you should be cleaning the data before hits the model, perhaps in the clean method of a form?

Comment: Last question, This doesn't affect other fields on the model, right?

Comment: @CarlBrubaker Not it won't, but be aware in my answer I change the method name from `clean` to `remove_x`, since clean is a `models.Model` method used for validation.